# How to get multiple class to BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-webbrowser

Trying to get torrent links from skidrowreloaded.

On the post detail page we have a div like this, I tried get this div by id but i think ***id is dynamic*** so I tried get this div ***by class*** but did not work,

```
<div id="tabs-105235-0-0" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
```

the following code is returning **none**

```
source2 = source.find("div", {"class": "ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"})
```

err:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

full code:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import webbrowser

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()
r = requests.get('https://www.skidrowreloaded.com/')
source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
source2 = source.find_all("h2")
games = []
for i in source2:
    games.append(i.a.get("href"))

lastgame = games[0]

r = requests.get(lastgame)
source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
source2 = source.find("div", {"class": "ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"})
source3 = source2.find_all("a")
k = 0;
for i in source3:
    if k == 0: #hide steam link.
        k = k + 1
    else:      
        if i.get("href") == "https://www.skidrowreloaded.com": #hide null links
            pass
        else: #throwing links to the browser
            print(i.get("href"))
            webbrowser.open(i.get("href"))   
        k = k + 1
```

Comment: Could u provide the entire html code?

Comment: Or even the link of the webpage would be fine.

Comment: sure, this is the last post from skidrow : https://www.skidrowreloaded.com/projection-first-light-goldberg/

Comment: Ok...So all u want is the text under About The Game. Am I right?

Comment: oh no, i need all "a" tags like MEGA, YANDEX ,TORRENT..   shortly if i can get the all "a" element from this div it enough for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the links try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.skidrowreloaded.com/projection-first-light-goldberg/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser").find_all("a", {"target": "_blank"})
skip = 'https://www.skidrowreloaded.com'
print([a['href'] for a in soup if a['href'].startswith('https') and a['href'] != skip])
```

Output:

```
['https://store.steampowered.com/app/726490/Projection_First_Light/', 'https://mega.nz/file/geogAATS#-0U0PklF-Q5i5l_SELzYx3klh5FZob9HaD4QKcFH_8M', 'https://uptobox.com/rqnlpcp7yb3v', 'https://1fichier.com/?0syphwpyndpo38af04ky', 'https://yadi.sk/d/KAmlsBmGaI1f2A', 'https://pixeldra.in/u/wmcsjuhv', 'https://dropapk.to/v6r7mjfgxjq6', 'https://gofile.io/?c=FRWL1o', 'https://racaty.net/dkvdyjqvg02e', 'https://bayfiles.com/L0k7Qea2pb', 'https://tusfiles.com/2q00y4huuv15', 'https://megaup.net/2f0pv/Projection.First.Light-GoldBerg.zip', 'https://letsupload.org/88t5', 'https://filesupload.org/0d7771dfef54d055', 'https://dl.bdupload.in/17ykjrifizrb', 'https://clicknupload.co/o0k9dnd3iwoy', 'https://dailyuploads.net/n1jihwjwdmjp', 'https://userscloud.com/nircdd4q1t5w', 'https://rapidgator.net/file/b6b8f5782c7c2bdb534214342b58ef18', 'https://turbobit.net/m308zh1hdpba.html', 'https://hitfile.net/5OhkcqZ', 'https://filerio.in/0wbvn4md4i91', 'https://mirrorace.org/m/1Fiic', 'https://go4up.com/dl/0ee9f4866312b5/Projection.First.Light-GoldBerg.zip', 'https://katfile.com/w74l823vuyw5/Projection.First.Light-GoldBerg.zip.html', 'https://multiup.org/download/3d355ba18d58234c792da7a872ab4998/Projection.First.Light-GoldBerg.zip', 'https://dl1.indishare.in/hs55pkx4ex82']
```

Comment: but if links were opening the tabs on the same page(so target wasn't defined) what should i do

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_all` as noted in the [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=find_all#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get("your URL here")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
raw_data = soup.find_all("div", class_="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom")
# do something with the data
```

edit -
looking at the `response.text`, the `div` exists, but does not have the `class` you're looking for, hence it returns empty. You can search by using regex like so

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get("your URL here")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
raw_data = soup.find_all("div", id=re.compile("^tabs"))
for ele in raw_data:
    a_tag = ele.find("a")
    # do something with the a_tag
```

Comment: i knew it, but my div is only one, there is no one div like this, so i think i should use "find" ?
i am trying to get all "a" tags from this div, but i couldn't reach to this div

Comment: I've updated the code in the edit. This does return a list of items to which you can continue searching.